# Particle Physics - minimum energy for $p + p \rightarrow p + p + \bar{p} + p$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, energy-conservation, mass-energy

> A beam of protons with energy $E_p$ is made to collide with a stationary target and a search for the interaction $p + p \rightarrow p + p + \bar{p} + p$ is made.

I have to estimate the minimum energy $E_p$ for this reaction to occur.

I think the minimum energy would correspond to when the produced protons have zero kinetic energy, so $E_p = 4m_p$.

However, this is not the answer. The solution goes on to say:

The initial invariant mass in the lab frame is $W_{initial}^2 = ((E_p + m_p)^2 - p^2)$ and then equates this to $(4m_p)^2$ to get $E_p = 7m_p$.

I have a few questions about this calculation:

- Why is the answer simply not $E_p = 4m_p$?
- Where does $(E_p + m_p)^2 - p^2$ come from? It seems to take into account the whole beam but only counts the mass of one proton (there are 2 incoming) as well as one proton momentum (again, are there not two)?
- Is there any significance in the question stating the target is stationary in this calculation?

Edit: I have attached a screenshot of the actual solution, just in case I have missed something out or the way I have written something leads to misinterpretation. [image]

Comment: "I think the minimum energy would correspond to when the produced protons have zero kinetic energy" - In which frame? You seem to think that the lab frame kinetic energy is the most important quantity to minimize; what's so special about your particular lab frame?

Comment: In the centre of momentum frame? But surely if the minimum energy corresponds to $4m_p$ in some frame, then that should be the minimum energy in every frame? To be honest, I'm not too confident with switching between the frames, so what I've just said might be a load of rubbish. Hopefully an answer will clear things up.

Comment: You're not firing two beams into each other, you're firing a single proton beam into a stationary target which is presumably made of atoms and thus is mostly protons. As such, you won't produce 4 stationary proton/anti-protons because that doesn't conserve momentum.

Comment: @jacob1729 I read the question as implying that only the two _produced_ antiprotons are stationary (in other words, only two of the four particles). This doesn't violate momentum conservation, if you allow the two final-state protons to have nonzero momenta.

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove The collision energy at which the produced antiprotons have zero kinetic energy (as measured in that frame) is different in every frame. For example, requiring that the two antiprotons have zero kinetic energy in the lab frame means that they're shooting backwards quite quickly in the center-of-momentum frame.

Comment: @probably_someone Only one anti-proton is produced? I think the question is correct, this is exactly how it is worded in the practice exam paper.

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove Oh, yes, sorry, that's correct. It doesn't really matter for the reasoning here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The initial invariant mass in the lab frame is $W_{initial}^2 = ((E_p + m_p)^2 - p^2)$ and then equates this to $(4m_p)^2$ to get $E_p = 7m_p$.

The total energy-momentum in the lab frame, stationary target, is (measuring momenta along direction of motion),
$$
(E +m, p), \implies W^2=  ((E + m)^2 - p^2).
$$

This is invariant: the same in all frames, and most notably in the center of momentum frame of all products. In that frame, hugely significant, you correctly inferred the energy/momentum of the reaction written (beam? what are you up to?) is 
$$
(4 m, 0), \implies W^2= 16 m^2.
$$
Equating the two, then, yields, given the initial $E^2=m^2+p^2$,
$$
E^2 + 2Em + m^2 -(E^2-m^2) -16 m^2 =0,
$$
solved to yield $E=7m$.

What is the problem? Remember, *E* is not a relativistic invariant, but *W* is. Initially, you are in the lab frame, but, finally, you are in the center of momentum frame.

Comment: Why is the momenta in the lab frame $E+ m$? Why is it not $E + 2m$ as you have two protons?

Comment: Careful: the 4-momentum vectors, which we write as a 2 vector here, as excluding the null momentum components, are  *(E,p)*, where *E* is the total energy, not the kinetic energy. As you see from later, it *includes m*! So the moving proton has $E_1=\sqrt{m^2+p^2}$, but the stationary target one has $E_2=m$.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't appreciated that one of the protons was stationary.